# nginx rewrite is relative to regexp

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to make a simple nginx rewrite using below line in location / block

```
location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
                ...
                rewrite ^/foo/(.*)$ /bar.html?p=$1 break;
...
}
```

rewrite expr matches url and directs request to `bar.html?p=$1` but the response page is relative to path `/foo/` that breaks the other html content with 404 due to missing /foo/ path in web folder.

The screenshot shows web dev console requests to /foo/ path. Why  rewriting is relative to rewrite regexp path `/foo/` ?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWbPK.png)

Comment: You use relative URLs in your HTML file to specify the resources. Either change `bar.html` so that the URLs for resources begin with a `/`, or use `rewrite...redirect` to change the URL at the browser.

Comment: Thank you Richard, you directed me to the solution to change urls in bar.html and saved my day.